# List with Headings for Grouped Sections

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to display a list of events grouped by date:

```
May 1
    Event 1
    Event 2
May 2
    Event 1
    Event 2
```

I still want to be able to target the groups of events using a CSS selector. For example:

```
May 1
    |=======|
    |Event 1|
    |Event 2|
    |=======|
May 2
    |=======|
    |Event 1|
    |Event 2|
    |=======|
```

What HTML tags would be the proper way to structure this?

---

I though about using a description list, but it seems difficult to target the event groups with a CSS selector. I can't see a great way to draw a box containing the May 1 events:

```html
<dl>
    <dt>May 1</dt>
    <dd>Event 1</dd>
    <dd>Event 2</dd>
    <dt>May 2</dt>
    <dd>Event 1</dd>
    <dd>Event 2</dd>
</dl>
```

Using divs seems like a great alternate, but it feels like I'm losing some stucture:

```html
<div>
    <div>May 1</div>
    <div>
        <div>Event 1</div>
        <div>Event 2</div>
    </div>
    <div>May 2</div>
    <div>
        <div>Event 1</div>
        <div>Event 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What @Paulie_D Said is more than enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this the *ideal* time to use a `ul/li` structure?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.dates {
  display: inline-block;
}

.date ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dates">
  <li class="date">Date 1
    <ul>
      <li>Event</li>
      <li>Event</li>
      <li>Event</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="date">Date 2
    <ul>
      <li>Event</li>
      <li>Event</li>
      <li>Event</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```